# Series expansion of the exponential function to a given power

Tags: calculus, power-series, exponential-function

It is verifiable that

${\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{n^k}{k!}=\left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k!}\right){}^n = e^n}$

How could one prove or show that

${\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{n^k}{k!}=\left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k!}\right){}^n}$ ?

Comment: Why go directly? It is easier to show that $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k/k!$ (either by assumption or from another definition) and that $e^{x+y}=e^x e^y$ (starting from whatever definition you chose), from which the result follows.

Comment: One way: first generalize it to $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{n^kx^k}{k!}=\left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^n$ and prove it using induction on $n$. This only requires knowledge of the binomial theorem (that being said the approach outlined above is the one I would go for).

Answer (score 0):

We will prove the statement by induction.

Let us first consider the base case. Observe we have
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!} \right)\left(\sum^\infty_{\ell = 0} \frac{1}{\ell !} \right) = \sum^\infty_{m=0}\sum_{k+\ell=m}\frac{1}{k!\ell!} = \sum^\infty_{m=0}\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k+\ell = m}\frac{m!}{k!\ell!} = \sum^\infty_{m=0}\frac{1}{m!}\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{m}{k}. 
\end{align}
Using the binomial theorem
\begin{align}
\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{m}{k} = 2^m
\end{align}
we have that
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!} \right)\left(\sum^\infty_{\ell = 0} \frac{1}{\ell !} \right) = \sum^\infty_{m=0}\frac{2^m}{m!}.
\end{align}

For the general case, we need to use the binomial theorem
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}y^k = (y+1)^n.
\end{align}

Suppose the statement holds for $n$, that is,
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!} \right)^n = \sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{n^k}{k!}
\end{align}
then observe we have
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!} \right)^n\left( \sum^\infty_{\ell=0}\frac{1}{\ell!}\right) = \left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{n^k}{k!} \right)\left(\sum^\infty_{\ell=0}\frac{1}{\ell!} \right) = \sum^\infty_{m=0} \frac{1}{m!}\sum^m_{k=0} \binom{m}{k}n^k = \sum^\infty_{m=0} \frac{(n+1)^m}{m!}.
\end{align}